# Using the same file pointer after resetting it, but ran into a problem

Tags: c

I am learning C, and is currently at handling files. I am trying to create a program that reads from a txt file, alter it a bit, then save it into a different txt file. So far, I have successfully wrote the program so that it reads from a txt file, and make changes to its content, and save it into a different file. The last thing I needeed to do was to print the new txt file's content, but I have ran into a problem.

What follows is the final part of the program where things seem to be going wrong.

```
ifp = fopen(buffer, "r");             //the array "buffer" stores the user input for the file name
rewind(ifp);                          //I have used ifp for reading the file to change, so I have resetted the file position.

while (1)
{
    file_char = fgetc(ifp);
    if (file_char == EOF) break;
    printf("%c", file_char);
}
```

I tried debugging the code, and the problem seems that the **fgetc(ifp)** part isn't working, resulting in **file_char** becoming EOF and the loop exiting. What's weird is that I have used the same code for reading the first txt file and it worked just fine, but doing the same thing resulted in this.

Here is the full code for better understanding of what I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* ifp, *ofp;
    char buffer[20];
    char file_char;

    printf("Input txt file name to change : ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    ifp = fopen(buffer, "r");
    while(1)
    {
        file_char = fgetc(ifp);
        if (file_char == EOF) break;
        printf("%c", file_char);
    }
    rewind(ifp);
    printf("Input txt file name to create : ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    ofp = fopen(buffer, "w");
    while (1)                                      //Changing contents of file
    {
        file_char = fgetc(ifp);
        if (file_char == EOF) break;
        if (file_char == '\n')
        {
            fprintf(ofp, "%c\n", file_char);
        }
        else
            fprintf(ofp, "%c", file_char);
    }
    ifp = fopen(buffer, "r");
    rewind(ifp);

    while (1)
    {
        file_char = fgetc(ifp);
        if (file_char == EOF) break;
        printf("%c", file_char);
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit)) To show what's going on, say I have a txt file named **a.txt**, with it's content being :

```
stackoverflow
123
```

Then what should happen when the program continues is:

```
Input txt file name to change : a.txt
stackoverflow
123
Input txt file name to create : b.txt
stackoverflow

123
```

and b.txt being created with it containing :

```
stackoverflow

123
```

But when I execute the program, it does :

```
Input txt file name to change : a.txt
stackoverflow
123
Input txt file name to create : b.txt
```

and **b.txt** being successfully created.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`. How would you be able to separate `EOF` from a valid `char` value?

Comment: I thought using a char variable would convert it to a char value, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Yes, it converts to `char`. That is the problem. Maybe not for your exact problem but it adds to it. If your `char` is unsigned it would never match `EOF` as this is a negative value.

Comment: `ifp` should be closed before being reused. And after a `fopen` in read mode, the file pointer is already at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Wow this solved the problem. You're a real life saver, thanks a lot!